# <T>T getInstance(final Class<T> type) why not Class<T> for both?

Tags: java, class, generics

So, I am delving into Java and curious about this type parameter usage.

```
<T>T getInstance
```

and then the arg

```
Class<T> type
```

I am a little confused here because if we require a return type, thus denoted by T then why isn't the arg the same... for instance

```
private static String getInstance(String arg)
```

So I'd figure it would be

```
private static Class<T> getInstance(final Class<T> type)
```

so, I am confused why the difference in expression of return type vs. argument

Comment: `T` is called a type parameter not a wildcard. A wildcard is `?`.

Comment: oops. thanks. i'll fix that.

Comment: `String` is a type. `Class` is a type. `Class` is not a placeholder for another type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to have the return type the same as the parameter type and by no means any rule that dictates that.

When a method is defined as

```
private static <T> T getInstance(final Class<T> type)
```

it means that the return object will be of type `T`, whereas the argument passed to the method is an instance of the generic `java.lang.Class` type parameterized to `T`.

This means the method may be invoked as follows:

```
String string = getInstance(String.class);
```

Hence this method takes an instance of type `Class` and returns an object of the type corresponding to this `Class` argument.

On the other hand, when the method is defined as

```
private static <T> T getInstance(final T type)
```

then you are forced to pass an object of type `T` in order to get the instance. Imagine it will be called as follows:

```
String string = getInstance("a");
```

Notice how the object "a" of type `String` is quite different than `String.class` of type `Class`.

Answer (score 4):

`T` and `Class<T>` are totally different.

The first says, "an object of some type, T." The second says, "an object of type `java.lang.Class`, which represents the class for some type `T`."

Put another way, here are two possible implementations:

```
Class<T> getInstance(Class<T> type) {
    return type;
}

T getInstance(Class<T> type) {
    return type.newInstance();
}
```

For instance, if `T` is a `String`, then the first of those will return `String.class`, and the second will return an empty string, `""`.

Answer (score 3):

Think of what the method does: it returns an `instance` from a `Class`.

Usage:

```
final String string = getInstance(String.class);
```

So what is the return - well it's `String`. And what is the argument - it's the `class String`, which is represented by `Class<String>`.

So the method signature becomes:

```
String getInstance(Class<String> string);
```

Parameterising out the `String` as `T` gives you the signature in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick that Java has implemented to combat the chicken-and-egg problem when you must create an object inside a type-erased generic method.

`Class<T>` is made generic so that you could call `getInstance` in a type-safe manner. Without `<T>` in the `Class` all of your `T`s would get erased, leaving you with

```
Object getInstance() {...}
```

and no way to get a reference of the class `T`, which has been erased.

Passing `Class<T>` solves this problem, because now the erased signature looks like this:

```
Object getInstance(Class cl) {...}
```

Although the type is erased again, now you have a `Class` object, which can be used as a "factory" to make new objects of class `T`. The fact that `Class<T>` is generic on the type that it creates lets Java compiler perform type checking, ensuring that the cast inserted implicitly by the compiler is going to succeed at runtime.

Comment: hmm. This is rather confusing. Offhand, do you have any references that delve into this a bit? I "get" what you are saying, but the details/nuances are escaping me.

Comment: @jamesemanon Here is [an article on generics explaining the use of class objects as runtime type tokens](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should distinguish a *class* from its *instance*. It can be tricky because in Java classes are also objects, and as such they also have a class (the class of the class!). Say:

```
class Foo { ... }
```

- An instance of Foo has type Foo;
- The class `Foo` itself is the (only) instance of another class, precisely `Class<Foo>`.

So in the above declaration, from left to right:

- `<T>` is the generic parameter, making the method a generic method;
- `T` is the return type: The method returns an instance of class `T`;
- `getInstance` is the name of the method;
- `Class<T>` means that you must pass as parameter the (only) instance of the class `T`, that itself has class `Class<Foo>`.

You can access such singleton instance by the implicit static field `Foo.class`. Every declared class has it, although you will not find it in the source code (tricky reflection issues).

Finally, why `Class` is generic? Well, to have something like that:

```
package java.lang;

public final class Class<T> {
   public static T newInstance();
   ...
}
```

so `Foo.class.newInstance()` returns a `Foo`, `Baz.class.newInstance()` returns a `Baz`, and so on. Neat, isn't it?